# Pan/zoom camera over a bezier path on a raster map in Apple Motion

Tags: camera, motion

1. I have imported a raster map into Apple Motion.
2. I have drawn a bezier path on top of the map and used the Write On behavior to make the path slowly reveal itself (like a travel map during any adventure movie showing the route taken).
3. I've added a camera so that I can zoom and pan the camera over the path as it appears.  However, as I attempt to move the camera over the route, the path itself shifts above the map surface, making the path inaccurate with relation to the underlying map.  Of course, this is because the angle of the camera is changing, which makes the path appear to shift on top of the map.

What I don't know is: how do I add camera moves over a Write On bezier path while not causing the path to appear to shift on the map? Obviously, I'm doing something wrong with the camera, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of experimentation, I have figured out the answer to this question. Make sure the raster map and bezier path are in the same group, open the group's inspector, click on the Group tab, and in the Group Controls section, check the "Flatten" checkbox.  Now, the bezier path will be flattened against the raster map, and there won't be any perspective issues when the camera flies around.